# Using pyinstaller in Ubuntu, error: No module named msvc

Tags: pyinstaller

I want to package a python file under Ubuntu 16.04. 
I input this command

```
pyinstaller -D -F -n main  "run_file.py"
```

However, it shows errors during processing:

> 3377 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 2, in 
>   ImportError: No module named win32com

It is weired. I use pyinstaller in ubuntu, then why it need win32com?
When I run the packaged executable file 
It shows an error:

> File "importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>   ImportError: No module named msvc

Any idea?

Comment: Contents of `run_file.py` (and possibly other files) are probably needed before anyone can answer this question, see [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried `hiddenimports=['setuptools.msvc']` on the Analysis object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--hidden-import=setuptools.msvc` parameter to invoke the `python pyinstaller` or fill the `hiddenimports=['setuptools.msvc']` in the Analysis object as @rafa suggested.